# Render h:panelGrid on dataTable row select?

Tags: jsf-2

I have a dataTable that when a user selects a row a number of fields are populated so they can see more detail. of that particular item. However, at the moment the page loads with the unpopulated panelgrid and populates on selecting of a row. How can I hide this panelgrid and get it to show once the row has been selected??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `rendered` attribute and let it evaluate `true` if anything has been selected.

E.g.

```
<h:panelGrid rendered="#{not empty bean.selectedRow}">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.selectedRow.foo}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.selectedRow.bar}" />
    ...
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Hmmm I thought this aswell but the panelgrid remains hidden. The dataTable is a primefaces datatable that uses the: onRowSelectUpdate="pnl-info" to update the values in the panelgrid, could this effect the use of the rendered attribute?

Comment: Put it in another element which is always rendered in the view and update that another element instead. E.g. `<h:panelGroup id="pnl-info"><h:panelGrid rendered="#{not empty bean.selectedRow}">`. The reason is that JS/Ajax needs the to-be-updated HTML DOM element to be already in the HTML DOM tree.

Comment: you sir are a gent! so simple and worked like a charm. Thankyou!